# qt eventfilter for qtreeview not working?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, qtreeview

I wish for an "event" to happen when enter key is pressed while a qtreeview is selected. As I prefer not to subclass qtreeview (easier for the designer) - I tried to install an event filter. However this didn't seem to work:

The class simply contains a public function:

```
bool InputTreeEventHandler::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) const {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyevent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        QTreeView* tree = dynamic_cast<QTreeView*>(obj);
        if (keyevent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) {
            //code
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the event is added like the following:

```
ui.InputTreeView->installEventFilter(InputTreeKeyboardEater.get());
```

Where `ui.InputTreeView` is the treeview I wish to act when pressing enter, and `InputTreeKeyboardEater` a (shared) pointer to  an object of `InputTreeEventHandler`

When putting a breakpoint at start of function above it shows the whole event handler isn't even called - what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)--`QObject::eventFilter` isn't const, which would explain your problem.  `InputTreeView` is looking to call a non-const version, which isn't there.  Also `eventFilter` is protected not public though I don't think that's critical.

Comment: thanks, I keep getting surprised by qt's "lack" of const-correctness :/

Comment: @paul23 why should the eventfilter function be const? The implementer might want to modify this - and this shouldn't require a cast...